# How to pass multiple parameters to the Web API controller methods in angular4

Tags: javascript, angular

Spring Rest Api :

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/save-userlist"}, method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveUserList(@RequestBody UserListDTO userListDTO, @RequestBody List<User> users, @RequestParam Integer userId) {
        ResponseEntity<?> response= null;
        try{
            logger.debug(userListDTO, );
                        logger.debug(users, );
                     return  ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("success");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            logger.debug(e.getMessage());
        }
        return  response;
    }
```

can anyone please suggest me how to pass multiple parameters to the Web-API from angular4

Comment: Did you try with this: @RequestParam Map<String,String> requestParams ?

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if i'm wrong but you can only pass 1 request body. Your request body should be 1 object which contains all your variables in json format, this will automatically be serialized to i.e. the UserListDRO object.

See [this example](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-requestbody-responsebody-example/):

> Method parameter user is marked with @RequestBody annotation. Thanks
>   to this annotation, Spring will try to bind the request body [which
>   can be JSON/XML/Other] to user object[ Means crating a new user object
>   with the details found in the request body like user name,age etc..],
>   based on Content-Type header in Http request.